# Code Mirror themes is not working in web pack

Tags: typescript, webpack, codemirror, webpack-style-loader

Actually, in my project, i need to show case the code snippet in highlighted version using code-mirror. But i am facing some issue with that.  Please check the below information.

Technical Background : Typescript, web pack.

Package Json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0"
  }
```

Web Pack config file

```
module: {
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            require.resolve('style-loader'),
            {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    url: false
                },
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

},

Actually, css file is loaded and but theming of code-mirror is not applied

[image: The html code is converted but not theme applied]

See the inspector mode

[image: See the themes are not applied]

Where did i commit the mistake.

In my index.ts file i import the code mirror like below

```
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror';

import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
import 'codemirror/mode/css/css.js';

import './codemirror.css';
import  './gruvbox-dark.css';
```

Then in function module, i transferred the code-snippet using code-mirror plugins as below.

```
myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(html element, {
            value: code-snippet content,
            lineNumbers: false,
            mode: 'text/html'
        });
```

Comment: can you show how you initialize Codemirror in your application?

Comment: @loveky, i have modified my description, with initialization of code mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use mode `text/html`, you should import `codemirror/mode/xml/xml`

Then, in codemirror configuration, add a `theme` field to enable your imported theme.

```
theme: 'gruvbox-dark'
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found the solution,

In order to use mode: 'text/html' in code mirror, i need to import the below file from node-modules.

import 'codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js';